# Extract data from an .aspx page

Tags: php, html, asp.net, file-get-contents, data-extraction

I am trying to read some data from this page: http://www.cefconnect.com/Pricing/DailyPricing.aspx using PHP.  I just need to get the list of ticker symbols that display on this page.  There are over 500 symbols which get updated every day.  It is a real nice page.  I can use my web browser and see that the data I need is nicely organized into the class called `ticker` in the HTML table. But, I can't seem to get this table to show up for me when I use `file_get_contents()` in PHP.  The reason is ( I think ), if you notice, the list of data actually takes a few seconds to load, so it is not loaded at first when the page initially loads.

I have done things like this before extracting data from "normal" HTML web pages.  I use this code which i was hoping would work.

```
$url = "http://www.cefconnect.com/Screener/FundScreener.aspx";
$page = file_get_contents($url);
echo $page;
```

When I do this, I get a lot of the code from the page, but the table which shows the data is missing.  I don't have any experience with ASPX pages, so I was hoping someone could point me in the right direction, hopefully accessing this data using PHP!  Thanks!

Comment: Use your browser's development tools or Fiddler and see what URL actually returns the data.

Comment: Yeah,m You should query `http://www.cefconnect.com/Resources/Funds/?props=CategoryId,SponsorId,IsLeveraged,LastUpdated,Cusip,Ticker,Name,CategoryName,NAV,LeverageRatio,DistributionRatePrice,Discount,MarketCap,ManagedDistribution` this url.

Comment: I was thinking that there was some other way to query for the data, because obviously the page was getting it from somewhere.  I was trying to look for the URL of a script to query but didn't see one.  I need to learn how to find that with the browser's dev tool.  I use Chrome.  @BogdanKuštan looks like that is the perfect query!

Answer (score 3):

The data appears to be loaded from another URL using Ajax. The data isn't included in the rendered HTML page from the server. You can find this URL using Chrome's developer tools etc.

I assume you have permission to use this site's data otherwise scraping their data is almost certainly an infringement of some kind.